# Postorder traversal to Levelorder and finding the level of a node

Tags: algorithm, tree, nodes, tree-traversal, postorder

I'm looking for a method or pseudo code to find the level of a particular node (the level in a level-ordered tree) which is written in post order string. I also appreciate any algorithm to convert a postorder string to level-order tree. 
I should mention that my tree includes both binary and unary functions.

Comment: Hi Hirad, welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you tried any solution to your problem? Do you have a specific problem that you face? Your question is very generic, please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to see what kind of questions that might get better response here.

Answer (score 0):

```
  C                    C
 / \        and       /
A   B                B
                    /
                   A

have the same postorder string: ABC...
```

but not the same level for every node, so you cannot determine the level from just the postorder traversal ordering